# Jackson - best way writes a java list to a json array

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to use jackson to convert a ArrayList to a JsonArray.

**Event.java** : this is the java bean class with two fields "field1", "field2" mapped as JsonProperty.

My goal is:

Convert

```
ArrayList<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>();
    list.add(new Event("a1","a2"));
    list.add(new Event("b1","b2"));
```

To

```
[
{"field1":"a1", "field":"a2"},
{"field1":"b1", "field":"b2"}
]
```

The way I can think of is:
**writeListToJsonArray()**:

```
public void writeListToJsonArray() throws IOException {  
    ArrayList<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>();
    list.add(new Event("a1","a2"));
    list.add(new Event("b1","b2"));

    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
    JsonGenerator jGenerator = jfactory.createJsonGenerator(out, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jGenerator.writeStartArray(); // [

    for (Event event : list) {
        String e = mapper.writeValueAsString(event);
        jGenerator.writeRaw(usage);
        // here, big hassles to write a comma to separate json objects, when the last object in the list is reached, no comma 
    }

    jGenerator.writeEndArray(); // ]

    jGenerator.close();

    System.out.println(out.toString());
}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
generator.write(out, list)
```

this directly convert the list to json array format and then write it to outputstream "out".

even greedier:

```
generator.write(out, list1)

generator.write(out, list2)
```

this will just convert/add in the list1, list2 into a single json array. then write it to "out"

Comment: Did you try `mapper.writeValueAsString(list)`? Or `mapper.writeValue(out, list)`.

Comment: yes, at the end mapper.writeValueAsString(list) does the trick, but My case is wanting to write multiple list back to back into a single JsonArray. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can create new list and add all lists to new one and convert is to json.

Comment: I can't merge the lists into a big list, I posted a separate question here if you want to take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516216/java-the-best-way-to-write-multiple-lists-back-to-back-to-a-single-jsonarray

Comment: So `usage` must be a field level object?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is overly complicated, Jackson handles lists via its writer methods just as well as it handles regular objects. This should work just fine for you, assuming I have not misunderstood your question:

```
public void writeListToJsonArray() throws IOException {  
    final List<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>(2);
    list.add(new Event("a1","a2"));
    list.add(new Event("b1","b2"));

    final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.writeValue(out, list);

    final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(new String(data));
}
```

Comment: yes, this works, thanks:) I guess my problem is more at adding multiple lists to a single jsonArray, mapper.writeValue(out, list1) mapper.writeValue(out, list2) .... mapper.writeValue(out, listn) is writing the list as separate json array, you get my point? I basically have incoming lists, i want to add them into a single jsonarray.

Comment: You can't write multiple lists back to back without them being tagged as properties, that would not be valid JSON.

Comment: you can write multiple arrays out if they are wrapped in an array

Comment: I don't know why, but I can't call the method `toByteArray()`. What I did instead was calling `toString()` directly on the OutputStream and it did produce a valid outcome. Is there something I miss?

Comment: @atrioom try using `StringWriter` as my answer posts

Comment: @AlexAffe 
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

instead of 

    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

and you will be able to call toByteArray()

Comment: For those wondering, if you want to ignore null values in the JSON object you can put this annotation on your object class @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL).

Answer (score 28):

I can't find `toByteArray()` as @atrioom said, so I use `StringWriter`, please try:

```
public void writeListToJsonArray() throws IOException {  

    //your list
    final List<Event> list = new ArrayList<Event>(2);
    list.add(new Event("a1","a2"));
    list.add(new Event("b1","b2"));


    final StringWriter sw =new StringWriter();
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.writeValue(sw, list);
    System.out.println(sw.toString());//use toString() to convert to JSON

    sw.close(); 
}
```

Or just use `ObjectMapper#writeValueAsString`:

```
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(list));
```

Answer (score 12):

In objectMapper we have writeValueAsString() which accepts object as parameter. We can pass object list as parameter get the string back.

```
List<Apartment> aptList =  new ArrayList<Apartment>();
    Apartment aptmt = null;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         aptmt= new Apartment();
         aptmt.setAptName("Apartment Name : ArrowHead Ranch");
         aptmt.setAptNum("3153"+i);
         aptmt.setPhase((i+1));
         aptmt.setFloorLevel(i+2);
         aptList.add(aptmt);
    }
mapper.writeValueAsString(aptList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Jackson the simplest way to do this is:

```
List<YourObject> yourList = new ArrayList<>();

// yourList - fill it with the data

final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {      
  System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(yourList));
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```