# java - the best way to write multiple lists back to back to a single JsonArray

Tags: java, json, jackson

My question is what's the best way to convert multiple lists back to back into a single JsonArray. The lists are coming on the fly, so I don't want to or I can't have all the lists(list1 - listn) merged in a big list, then use Jackson to write the merged list to a JsonArray.

Convert

```
ArrayList<Event> list1 = new ArrayList<Event>();
    list1.add(new Event("a1","a2"));
    list1.add(new Event("b1","b2"));

ArrayList<Event> list2 = new ArrayList<Event>();
    list2.add(new Event("c1","c2"));
    list2.add(new Event("d1","d2"));
......
......listn
```

To a single jsonArray:

```
[
{"field1":"a1", "field2":"a2"},
{"field1":"b1", "field2":"b2"},
{"field1":"c1", "field2":"c2"},
{"field1":"d1", "field2":"d2"},
......
{"field1":"n1", "field2":"n2"}
]
```

Comment: Im trying to understand the question: You have multiple lists where? in class? Lets say you succeeded to convert all lists (1,2 .. n) to Gson/Jackson string. Now you want to convert it back to list of arrays, true?

Comment: let me give a bit more background here, I query the underlying DB in a batch mode, so let's say 10 records at a time. They come back as a list with 10 records. Then we my API is streaming(outputstream) the single jsonArray as the return. All of these is because the resultSet can be extremely big, we don't want to have out of memory issues anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, I found out that there is no such way in Jackson allowing you directly write two lists back to back into a JsonArray. You can either implement JsonGenerator with your own implementation writeStartArray() writeEndArray() OR even easier, you can just define the startArray and endArray, and construct the jsonArray by yourself

```
private static final String JSON_ARRAY_START = "[" + LINE_BREAK;
private static final String JSON_ARRAY_COMMA = "," + LINE_BREAK;
private static final String JSON_ARRAY_END = LINE_BREAK+ "]";
```

so code will roughly look like:

```
write(JSON_ARRAY_START)
foreach list1
    use objectMapper write every Event object
    write(JSON_ARRAY_COMMA)
foreach list2
    use objectMapper write every Event object
    if it's not the last element in the list, write(JSON_ARRAY_COMMA)
write(JSON_ARRAY_END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `Jackson` but looking at the `API` I would do sth like this:

1. Create a custom implementation of `WriterBasedJsonGenerator` (or any `JsonGenerator` you use) that modifies the behaviour a bit:

```
    public MyJsonGenerator extends WriterBasedJsonGenerator {
        @Override
        public void writeStartArray () {// do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void writeEndArray () {// do nothing
        }
    }
```

1. Than before writing the first `ArrayList` I would do

   ```
   generator.writeRaw ('[');
   ```

Before the next lists

```
generator.writeRaw (',');
```

And after the last list

```
generator.writeRaw (']');
```