# Passing List<CustomObj> from backend into the model to be used in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a large set of data that I am working with that is contained within some custom Java objects.  The creation and management of those items/objects lives somewhere else and is not relevant to this problem.

In my Spring Controller I have a function setup to return a string `index` which is returning to the front end as our `index.jsp` page.  I am using the `Model model` as a parameter of this so I can add attributes in that I will need to display in the `jsp`, I.E. ids, Strings, etc.  In the model, I also want to store a `List<CustomObj>` that I can then work with in Javascript.  For now the way I am doing this is with `model.addAttribute("customList", javaListObjectHere);`.  (NOTE: I have also tried using `ModelAndView` and doing `.addObject()` without seeing any differences)

The Javascript lives outside the JSP since it is more complex, but still needs that list of objects to display.  I have tried using a `<script>` in the head of my jsp to set a `var listOfObjs = "${customList}"` and then try and do things in the JS with `listOfObjs` which have not worked.  Since it is a list, is there something special I need to do when declaring the `var` and then iterate over the list to put items in?

I have seen ways to handle this if my `ArrayList` was holding `String`, but it is instead holding a more complex object type.  The simple way to push things into Strings in JS didn't seem to work for complex types.

It seems like something that has been done before and our current solution won't work long term (having the JS make an AJAX call to get that list independently).

TLDR: I have a list of custom java objects I want to put into my Spring model.  I want to then (in JSP) store that to a Javascript variable so I have access to it outside of that JSP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a Java ArrayList of strings to a JavaScript array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440164/converting-a-java-arraylist-of-strings-to-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @AlanHay I don't think this is a duplicate.  There are MANY questions about how to handle Strings and lists of Strings, this deals with custom POJO Java objects.  It is a lot more difficult to cast/handle/deal with non basic types like Strings or Ints.

Comment: Use Jackson or Gson to convert to a JSON array on the Server side and add that to your model (as well as the list if you require that elsewhere). Then output this JSON attribute in your JS code. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514570/jackson-best-way-writes-a-java-list-to-a-json-array. You can then work with this JSON array in your JS code.