# Java ArrayList to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, arraylist

i have a Java ArrayList and i want to send it to the javascript for another purpose.

this is my Java ArrayList

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("xxx");
list.add("yyy");
....

model.addAttribute("theList", list);
```

and how to send the ArrayList into javascript Array?

i'm expecting this in my javascript code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

 var Array = ["xxx","yyy","xxx"];

</script>
```

i'm truly sorry for asking this type of question again, i know there's already answered questions and duplictae questions about this case, but i don't really understand the answer. maybe some JSON things or other ways.
please show me how to write the code both in java code and javascript code.
Thanks.

Comment: If there are duplicate questions and you don't understand the answers, the best way would be to dig around the internet until you do understand them. What you should do is use a JSON serialization library such as https://github.com/google/gson, and just convert your ArrayList to a JSON array using toJson (https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a library to serialize the object as a json string. In other words, you can convert each list element to a json object node and put all the json object nodes into an array.

**What a serializer does**

It takes a look at your object(s) and creates a json representation out of it/them (serializes). The opposite of a serializer is a deserializer, to convert a json string into Java objects.

**Why use a library**

While you could do it by hand (see below), a library such as Gson as mentioned in the comments, or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki) in the open source community has been tested on a large number of test cases and will in all likelihood be robust enough for whatever your use case is.

**Example with jackson**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514570/jackson-best-way-writes-a-java-list-to-a-json-array).

**Example "do it yourself"**

Your case is very simple since your list elements are strings.

```
// create a string builder to build the json
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// loop over each string in the list
for (String s : list) {
    // add an initial delimiter, which will be 
    // removed at the end
    sb.append(",");

    // add a beginning quote to each term
    sb.append("\""); 

    // add the string
    sb.append(s);

    // close the quote
    sb.append("\"");
}

if (sb.length() > 0) {
    // if there was at least one element
    // in the list, remove the initial comma
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
}

// add a left square bracket
sb.insert(0, "[");

// add a right square bracket
sb.append("]");

// your string, for example
// ["one","two","three"]
String json = sb.toString();
```

Going back to "why use a library", the above code doesn't account for a lot of possibilities, the most obvious of which, if one of the strings in the list contains a " character it will mess everything up. Note that there are many ways to handle the above.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlet tag allows to write Java code into JSP file.

Syntax

```
<% java code %>
```

Here <%%> tags are scriplets tag and within it, we can place java code.

```
`<% List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("xxx");
strList.add("yyy");
strList.add("zzz");%>`
```

`var jsArray = [<% for (int i = 0; i < strList.size(); i++) { %>"<%= strList.get(i) %>"<%= i + 1 < strList.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];`

The output will be

```
var jsArray = ["xxx","yyy","zzz"];
```