# Objects not properly saving to & loading from JSON file

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am creating an application where I have a `saveToStorage()` and `loadFromStorage()` methods, but I can't see the flashcards being saved to FlashcardList, neither they are loaded when I restart the application.

**code block where this procedure is supposed to happen**

```
@FXML
private void handleNewButton() {
  try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("single_flashcard.fxml"));
      Parent root = loader.load();

      SingleFlashcardController singleFlashcardController = loader.getController();
      // Perform any additional initialization or passing data to the singleFlashcardController if needed

      singleFlashcardController.setStage(new Stage());
      singleFlashcardController.setFlashcardList(flashcardList); // Pass the flashcardList to the SingleFlashcardController

      Stage stage = singleFlashcardController.getStage();
      stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
      stage.show();

      // After the flashcard is saved, retrieve the flashcard data from singleFlashcardController
      singleFlashcardController.getStage().setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
          Flashcard flashcard = singleFlashcardController.getFlashcard();
          if (flashcard != null) {
              saveFlashcardsToStorage(flashcardList);
          }
      });

  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private void saveFlashcardsToStorage(List<Flashcard> flashcards) {
  try {
      File file = new File("flashcards.json");
      saveFlashcardsToFile(flashcards, file);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // Handle exception appropriately
  }
}

private void saveFlashcardsToFile(List<Flashcard> flashcards, File file) throws IOException {
  if(flashcards!=null) {
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      objectMapper.writeValue(file, flashcards.toArray(new Flashcard[0]));
  }
}

public List<Flashcard> loadFlashcardsFromStorage() {
  if(flashcardList!=null) {
      flashcardList.clear();
  }
  List<Flashcard> flashcards = new ArrayList<>();

  try {
      File file = new File("flashcards.json");
      if (file.exists()) {
          flashcards = loadFlashcardsFromFile(file);
          if(flashcardList!=null) {
              flashcardList.addAll(flashcards);
          }
      }
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      // Handle exception appropriately
  }

  return flashcards;
}

private List<Flashcard> loadFlashcardsFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  Flashcard[] flashcards = objectMapper.readValue(file, Flashcard[].class);
  return Arrays.asList(flashcards);
}
```

Code of **SingleFlashcardController class** where a new flashcard is created and being saved to storage:

```
@FXML
    private void handleSaveButton() {
    String question = questionTextField.getText();
    String answer = answerTextArea.getText();        
    // Update the flashcard with the new question and answer

    if(flashcard!=null) {
        flashcard.setQuestion(question);
        flashcard.setAnswer(answer);
    }

    // Save the flashcard to storage
    saveFlashcardToStorage(flashcard);

    // Update the flashcard in the flashcardList if it exists
    if(flashcardList!=null) {
        int index = flashcardList.indexOf(flashcard);
        if (index != -1) {
            flashcardList.set(index, flashcard);
        }
    }

    // Notify the showFlashcardController of the updated flashcard
    if (showFlashcardController != null) {
        showFlashcardController.setFlashcard(flashcard);
    }

    // Close the stage
    closeStage();

    // Clear the input fields
    clearFields();
}

private void clearFields() {
    questionTextField.clear();
    answerTextArea.clear();
}
```

Initially the methods were getting saved to Flashcard ListView atleast, then I dont know where the changes made impacted the code that now that `saveFlashcardstoStorage()` even isn't working.

In case you need the complete code to see where implementation is going wrong, code is as follows:
**FlashcardScreenController class:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.*;

public class FlashcardScreenController implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private Button deleteButton;
    private Controller deckScreenController;

    public void setDeckScreenController(Controller deckScreenController) {
        this.deckScreenController = deckScreenController;
    }

    private ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController;
    private SingleFlashcardController singleFlashcardController;

    public void setSingleFlashcardController(SingleFlashcardController singleFlashcardController) {
        this.singleFlashcardController = singleFlashcardController;
    }

    public void setShowFlashcardController(ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController) {
        this.showFlashcardController = showFlashcardController;
    }

    @FXML
    private ListView<Flashcard> flashcardListView;
    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Flashcard> flashcardList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private Label titleLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label questionLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label answerLabel;

    private Deck deck;

    @FXML
    private Button backButton;
    private Flashcard flashcard;

    private static FlashcardScreenController instance;

    public FlashcardScreenController() {
        instance = this;
    }

    public static FlashcardScreenController getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setFlashcard(Flashcard flashcard) {
        this.flashcard = flashcard;
        questionLabel.setText(flashcard.getQuestion());
        answerLabel.setText(flashcard.getAnswer());
    }

    public void setDeck(Deck deck) {
        this.deck = deck;
        titleLabel.setText(deck.getName());


        // Clear the flashcardList before adding elements
        flashcardList.clear();

        // Populate the flashcards list from the deck
        if (deck != null) {
            Collection<Flashcard> flashcards = deck.getFlashcards();
            if (flashcards != null) {
                flashcardList.addAll(flashcards);
            }
        }
        flashcardListView.setCellFactory(listView -> new FlashcardCell());
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        loadFlashcardsFromStorage(); // Load flashcards when the controller is initialized

        flashcardListView.setCellFactory(listView -> new FlashcardCell());
        flashcardListView.setItems(flashcardList);

        flashcardListView.sceneProperty().addListener((observable, oldScene, newScene) -> {
            if (newScene != null) {
                Stage stage = (Stage) flashcardListView.getScene().getWindow();
                if (stage != null) {
                    // Set the close request handler
                    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> closeFlashcardScreen());
                }
            }
        });

        flashcardListView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            if (event.getClickCount() == 2) {
                Flashcard selectedFlashcard = flashcardListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if (selectedFlashcard != null) {
                    instance.openSingleFlashcardView(selectedFlashcard);
                }
            }
        });

        // Initialize titleLabel here
        titleLabel.setText("Flasho");

        if (showFlashcardController != null) {
            showFlashcardController.setFlashcardList(flashcardList);
            // Set the flashcardList in the ShowFlashcardController
        }

        setShowFlashcardController(showFlashcardController); // Pass the ShowFlashcardController instance to FlashcardScreenController

        backButton.setOnAction(this::handleBackButtonAction);
    }


    public void openSingleFlashcardView(Flashcard flashcard) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("showFlashcard.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController = loader.getController();
            showFlashcardController.setFlashcard(flashcard);

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Flashcard");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

            // Pass the FlashcardScreenController instance to the ShowFlashcardController
            showFlashcardController.setFlashcardScreenController(this);

            // After the single flashcard view is closed, update the flashcard if it was modified
            if(singleFlashcardController != null) {
                if (singleFlashcardController.isFlashcardModified()) {
                    Flashcard modifiedFlashcard = singleFlashcardController.getFlashcard();
                    // Update the flashcard in the flashcard list
                    flashcardList.set(flashcardList.indexOf(flashcard), modifiedFlashcard);

                    // Update the flashcard in the ShowFlashcardController
                    setFlashcard(modifiedFlashcard);
                }
            }

            stage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleNewButton() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("single_flashcard.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            SingleFlashcardController singleFlashcardController = loader.getController();
            // Perform any additional initialization or passing data to the singleFlashcardController if needed

            singleFlashcardController.setStage(new Stage());
            singleFlashcardController.setFlashcardList(flashcardList); // Pass the flashcardList to the SingleFlashcardController

            Stage stage = singleFlashcardController.getStage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();

            // After the flashcard is saved, retrieve the flashcard data from singleFlashcardController
            singleFlashcardController.getStage().setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                Flashcard flashcard = singleFlashcardController.getFlashcard();
                if (flashcard != null) {
                    saveFlashcardsToStorage(flashcardList);
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveFlashcardsToStorage(List<Flashcard> flashcards) {
        try {
            File file = new File("flashcards.json");
            saveFlashcardsToFile(flashcards, file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }
    }

    private void saveFlashcardsToFile(List<Flashcard> flashcards, File file) throws IOException {
        if(flashcards!=null) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, flashcards.toArray(new Flashcard[0]));
        }
    }

    public List<Flashcard> loadFlashcardsFromStorage() {
        if(flashcardList!=null) {
            flashcardList.clear();
        }
        List<Flashcard> flashcards = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            File file = new File("flashcards.json");
            if (file.exists()) {
                flashcards = loadFlashcardsFromFile(file);
                if(flashcardList!=null) {
                    flashcardList.addAll(flashcards);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }

        return flashcards;
    }

    private List<Flashcard> loadFlashcardsFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Flashcard[] flashcards = objectMapper.readValue(file, Flashcard[].class);
        return Arrays.asList(flashcards);
    }


    public void displayFlashcards(Deck deck) {
        if (flashcardList != null) {
            flashcardList.clear();

            if (deck != null) {
                Collection<Flashcard> flashcards = deck.getFlashcards();
                if (flashcards != null) {
                    flashcardList.addAll(flashcards);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /* handling switching to single flashcard */
    @FXML
    private void handleFlashcardClick(MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getClickCount() == 2) { // Double-click event
            Flashcard selectedFlashcard = flashcardListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if (selectedFlashcard != null) {
                openSingleFlashcardView(selectedFlashcard);
            }
        }
    }


    private void openSingleFlashcardEditView(Flashcard flashcard) {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("single_flashcard.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            SingleFlashcardController singleFlashcardController = loader.getController();
            singleFlashcardController.setStage(new Stage());
            singleFlashcardController.setFlashcard(flashcard);

            Stage stage = singleFlashcardController.getStage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();

            // After the single flashcard edit view is closed, update the flashcard if it was modified
            if (singleFlashcardController.isFlashcardModified()) {
                Flashcard modifiedFlashcard = singleFlashcardController.getFlashcard();
                // Update the flashcard in the flashcard list
                flashcardList.set(flashcardList.indexOf(flashcard), modifiedFlashcard);

                // Update the flashcard in the show flashcard controller
                ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController = loader.getController();
                showFlashcardController.setFlashcard(modifiedFlashcard);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void closeFlashcardScreen() {
        // Hide the flashcard screen
        Stage stage = (Stage) backButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.hide();

        if (deckScreenController != null) {
            // Show the deck screen
            deckScreenController.showDeckScreen();
        }

        saveFlashcardsToStorage(flashcardList);

        //reload decks when FlashcardScreen si closed
        if (deckScreenController != null) {
            deckScreenController.loadDecks();
        }
    }



    public void initializeFlashcardScreen(Deck deck) {
        if (deck != null) {
            if(flashcardList!=null) {
                flashcardList.clear();
            }
            Collection<Flashcard> flashcards = deck.getFlashcards();
            if (flashcards != null) {
                flashcardList.addAll(flashcards);
            }



            flashcardListView.setItems(flashcardList);

            flashcardListView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Flashcard>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Flashcard flashcard, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(flashcard, empty);
                    if (empty || flashcard == null) {
                        setText(null);
                    } else {
                        setText(flashcard.getQuestion());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void switchToDeckScreen() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();

            Controller deckController = loader.getController();
            deckController.initializeDeckScreen();

            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("Deck");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();

            // Set the close request handler for the new stage
            stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                deckController.closeDeckScreen();
                event.consume();
            });

            // Hide the flashcard screen
            Stage flashcardScreenStage = (Stage) backButton.getScene().getWindow();
            flashcardScreenStage.hide();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleBackButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        switchToDeckScreen();
    }

    public void showFlashcardScreen() {
        try {
            // Save the flashcards to storage
            saveFlashcardsToStorage(flashcardList);

            // Retrieve the stage of the current controller
            Stage currentStage = (Stage) flashcardListView.getScene().getWindow();

            // Load the FXML file for the deck screen
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("flashcardScreen.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            FlashcardScreenController flashcardScreenController = loader.getController();

            // Set any necessary data or configurations on the deck screen controller
            // ...

            // Create a new stage for the deck screen
            Stage flashcardScreenStage = new Stage();
            flashcardScreenStage.setTitle("Flashcard Screen");
            flashcardScreenStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

            // Hide the current stage and show the flashcard screen stage
            currentStage.hide();
            flashcardScreenStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Handle the exception appropriately (e.g., show an error message)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* DELETE BUTTON */
    @FXML
    private void handleDeleteButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Flashcard selectedFlashcard = flashcardListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selectedFlashcard != null) {
            flashcardList.remove(selectedFlashcard);
            // Save the updated flashcard list
            File file = new File("flashcards.json");
            saveFlashcardsToStorage(flashcardList);
        }
    }
}
```

**SingleFlashcardController class:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.PrimitiveIterator;

public class SingleFlashcardController {
    private boolean editMode = false;
    private boolean flashcardModified;
    @FXML
    private Button editButton;

    @FXML
    private Button saveButton;


    @FXML
    private Label questionLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label answerLabel;

    private List<Flashcard> flashcards = new ArrayList<>();
    private ObservableList<Flashcard> flashcardList;

    @FXML
    private TextField questionTextField;

    @FXML
    private TextArea answerTextArea;

    private Stage stage;
    private Flashcard flashcard;

    private ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController;

    public void setShowFlashcardController(ShowFlashcardController showFlashcardController) {
        this.showFlashcardController = showFlashcardController;
    }

    public void setFlashcardList(ObservableList<Flashcard> flashcardList) {
        this.flashcardList = flashcardList;
    }

    public void setFlashcard(Flashcard flashcard) {
        this.flashcard = flashcard;
        // Update the UI components with the flashcard data
        questionTextField.setText(flashcard.getQuestion());
        answerTextArea.setText(flashcard.getAnswer());
    }

    public Flashcard getFlashcard() {
        String question = questionTextField.getText();
        String answer = answerTextArea.getText();

        // Perform any necessary validation or processing on the question and answer

        if (!question.isEmpty() && !answer.isEmpty()) {
            return new Flashcard(question, answer);
        } else {
            // Return null or handle the case when the flashcard is not valid
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Set up event handlers
        questionTextField.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleQuestionTextFieldClick);
        answerTextArea.setOnMouseClicked(this::handleAnswerTextAreaClick);

        questionTextField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (!newValue) {
                questionTextField.setEditable(false);
            }
        });

        answerTextArea.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(!newValue) {
                answerTextArea.setEditable(true);
            }
        });

        if (showFlashcardController != null) {
            showFlashcardController.setFlashcardList(flashcardList); // Set the flashcardList in the ShowFlashcardController
        }
            setShowFlashcardController(showFlashcardController); // Pass the ShowFlashcardController instance to FlashcardScreenController
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleQuestionTextFieldClick(MouseEvent event) {
        // Allow user to start writing when the question text field is clicked
        questionTextField.setEditable(true);
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleAnswerTextAreaClick(MouseEvent event) {
        // Allow user to start writing when the answer text area is clicked
        answerTextArea.setEditable(true);
    }


    @FXML
    private void handleSaveButton() {
        String question = questionTextField.getText();
        String answer = answerTextArea.getText();

        // Update the flashcard with the new question and answer
        if(flashcard!=null) {
            flashcard.setQuestion(question);
            flashcard.setAnswer(answer);
        }

        // Save the flashcard to storage
        saveFlashcardToStorage(flashcard);

        // Update the flashcard in the flashcardList if it exists
        if(flashcardList!=null) {
            int index = flashcardList.indexOf(flashcard);
            if (index != -1) {
                flashcardList.set(index, flashcard);
            }
        }

        // Notify the showFlashcardController of the updated flashcard
        if (showFlashcardController != null) {
            showFlashcardController.setFlashcard(flashcard);
        }

        // Close the stage
        closeStage();

        // Clear the input fields
        clearFields();
    }

    private void clearFields() {
        questionTextField.clear();
        answerTextArea.clear();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleEditButtonClick(ActionEvent event){
        questionTextField.setEditable(true);
        answerTextArea.setEditable(true);

        if (showFlashcardController != null) {
            showFlashcardController.enableEditButton();
        }
    }
    public Stage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    // Method to check if the flashcard was modified
    public boolean isFlashcardModified() {
        return flashcardModified;
    }

    private void handleCloseButton() {
        closeStage();
    }

    private void closeStage() {
        if(stage!=null) {
            stage.close();
        }
    }

    public void openSingleFlashcardView() {
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    public void initializeFlashcard(Flashcard flashcard, boolean editMode) {
        // Set the flashcard data

        // Toggle visibility of elements based on edit mode
        if (editMode) {
            if(questionLabel!=null){
            questionLabel.setVisible(false);}
            if(questionTextField!=null){
            questionTextField.setVisible(true);}
            questionTextField.setText(flashcard.getQuestion());

            if(answerLabel!=null){
            answerLabel.setVisible(false);}
            if(answerTextArea!=null){
            answerTextArea.setVisible(true);}
            answerTextArea.setText(flashcard.getAnswer());

        } else {
            if(questionLabel!=null){
            questionLabel.setVisible(true);}
            if(questionTextField!=null){
            questionTextField.setVisible(false);}
            questionLabel.setText(flashcard.getQuestion());

            if(answerLabel!=null){
            answerLabel.setVisible(true);}
            if(answerTextArea!=null){
            answerTextArea.setVisible(false);}
            answerLabel.setText(flashcard.getAnswer());
        }

        this.editMode = editMode;
    }

    private void saveFlashcardToStorage(Flashcard flashcard) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            File file = new File("flashcards.json");
            List<Flashcard> flashcards = loadFlashcardsFromStorage();

            // Find the index of the flashcard in the flashcards list
            int index = -1;
            if (flashcards != null) {
                index = flashcards.indexOf(flashcard);
            }

            if (index != -1) {
                // Update the flashcard in the list
                flashcards.set(index, flashcard);
            } else {
                // Add the new flashcard to the list
                flashcards.add(flashcard);
            }

            // Save the updated flashcards list to the file
            objectMapper.writeValue(file, flashcards);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }
    }

    private List<Flashcard> loadFlashcardsFromStorage() {
        List<Flashcard> flashcards = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            File file = new File("flashcards.json");
            if (file.exists()) {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                flashcards = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<List<Flashcard>>() {});
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle exception appropriately
        }

        return flashcards;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `FlashCard` have `JavaFX` properties? If so, does `Jackson` support `JavaFX` properties? Why are you doing `objectMapper.writeValue(file, flashcards.toArray(new Flashcard[0]));` instead of `objectMapper.writeValue(file, flashcards);`? I have never liked `Jackson` so I don't have much experience with it, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514570/jackson-best-way-writes-a-java-list-to-a-json-array), it should work.

Comment: Due to a [moderator/volunteer strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderator-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-and?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) I will not be performing any content curation on this question.

Comment: Can you reply to this now?